# Pass div tag into Javascript function with two arguments

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to pass `html` `div tag` into the below `Javascript` `function`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function fire(message, type) {
            {
                var cssclass;
                switch (type) {
                    case 'Error':
                        cssclass = 'alert-danger'
                        break;
                    case 'Warning':
                        cssclass = 'alert-warning'
                        break;
                    default:
                        cssclass = 'alert-info'
                }
            }

            var elem2 = document.createElement('div');
            //elem2.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><span><strong>unbelievable</strong></span></div>'; works.
            elem2.innerHTML = '<div class="alert '+type+' alert-dismissible fade show"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><span><strong>'+message+'</strong ></span ></div > ';
            document.body.appendChild(elem2);
        }

    </script>
```

Still on the `file.aspx`,

I have defined

`<asp:Label ID="lblJavaScript" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>`

Then called on the `file.cs`, for testing purposes:

```
 lblJavaScript.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>fire('test', 'Error');</script>";
```

What strike me the most is the lack of colored box framing the variable `test`  as highlighted from the `hard-coded` syntax:

```
elem2.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><span><strong>unbelievable</strong></span></div>';
```

. Thus I am keen on knowing the rationale. Thanks in advance for relevant explanations.

Comment: What do you want  to test with `lblJavaScript.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>fire('test', 'Error');</script>";`?

Comment: the appearance of the ```Bootstrap box``` called via the ```div class```

Answer (score 0):

As a way around, I have defined the following `script`, by hoping that it would help others experiencing a similar matter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function fire(message, type) {
            {
                var cssclass;
                var csscolor;
                switch (type) {
                    case 'Success':
                        cssclass = 'alert-success'
                        csscolor = '#28a745'
                        break;
                    case 'Error':
                        cssclass = 'alert-danger'
                        csscolor = '#dc3545'
                        break;
                    case 'Warning':
                        cssclass = 'alert-warning'
                        //csscolor = '#f0ad4e'
                        csscolor = '#ffc107'
                        break;
                    default:
                        cssclass = 'alert-info'
                        csscolor = '#17a2b8'
                }
            }

var elem2 = document.createElement('div');

elem2.innerHTML = '<div class="alert ' + type + ' alert-dismissible fade show" style="margin: 0 0.5%; -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 4px 6px #999;background-color:' + csscolor+'"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><span><strong>'+message+'</strong ></span ></div > ';
            document.body.appendChild(elem2);
}

</script>
```